# jquery and css not added to ajax response

Tags: jquery, css, ajax

Working on slider but the script which are added at run time  is not getting added in ajax response .does anyone know why

```
$.ajax({
    url:"ajax_get_response_eng_to_change.php",
    type:"POST",
    async:true,
    data:{cat_id:"cat_id",obj:obj } ,
    beforeSend: function(){

        }   
    })
    .done(function(resp){ 
          thumbGallerySetupDone();
             var json_obj = jQuery.parseJSON(resp); 


            var output=   
"<div class='a2' style='display: block;height: 185px;color:white' id='outg"+obj+"'>"+
           "<div id='componentWrapper' >"+
             "<div class='thumbContainer'>"+
                "<div class='thumbInnerContainer' id='g"+obj+"'>";
                for (var i in json_obj) 
               {
output+= "<div class='thumbHolder'><a class='pp_content' data-rel='prettyPhoto[gallery1]' href='administrator/public/upload/"+json_obj[i].cat_meta_img+"' title='"+json_obj[i].sub_n+"' ><img  class='thumb_hidden' src='administrator/public/upload/"+json_obj[i].cat_meta_img+"' width='180' height='120'/></a> </div>>";
                    } 

    output+= "</div></div> <div class='thumbBackward thumb_hidden' id='previo'><img src='data/icons/thumb_backward.png' alt='' width='21' height='31' /></div>  <div class='thumbForward thumb_hidden' id='nexta' ><img src='data/icons/thumb_forward.png' alt='' width='21' height='31' /></div></div></div>";


        $("#prev_response").append(output);

        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be problem is because of `async:true` as it does't wait for ajax call to complete so may be it's happening.

Try using `async:false` (Not tested).

Comment: ok making change, one more thing ,all the script and css for this gallery ,is added of main page not the resplose ,is it making a differencs

Comment: Make sure that script and css is executed first

Comment: it is taking time ,as time limit over it will accept